# Find the exact value of expression $S=\sqrt{4+\sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt[4]{4+\sqrt[5]{4+\sqrt[6]{4+\cdots}}}}}$

Tags: closed-form, nested-radicals

Let
$$S=\sqrt{4+\sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt[4]{4+\sqrt[5]{4+\sqrt[6]{4+\cdots}}}}}$$
Is it possible to write $S$ in terms of standard mathematical functions and operators? If yes, what is the exact value of $S$? If not, can it be proved?

Comment: This looks really close to this question
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837189/evaluating-the-sum-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt22-sqrt32-sqrt42-cdots-s

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: One would be better off folding these into one question, I suppose---if not for the fact that I really have no expectation of their being a solution...

Comment: I think that there is no solution. But, I want to see the proof.

Comment: Would you be satisfied by some evidence/reasoning of why this problem appears analytically intractable?

Comment: The question of whether a "closed form answer" exists depends on what you admit as closed forms. For example, if one accepts zeros of arbitrary hypergeometic functions, it might be very difficult to prove that a given expression has no closed form value. I would modify this problem to that of even proving that the expression's limit is not rational; a talented mathematician could very possibly show that.  Showing that it is transcendental would be a *lot* harder.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662563/nice-way-to-express-the-radical-sqrt4-sqrt34-sqrt44-dots
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782032/find-sqrt4-sqrt34-sqrt44-sqrt54
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843974/value-of-y-sqrt4-sqrt34-sqrt44-sqrt54-ldots